# Google script, active cell after script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that inserts a new row (8)in a spreadsheet and copies data from row 9. The script is triggered from a button linked to the script. Everything works fine except when the script is finished and I start typing I don't see any data. The new row 8/col 3 should be active. It does have a blue box around it, but doesn't accept data until I click on it.

```
function InsertTran() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
  var row = 8;
  var newrow = 9;
  //var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.getRange('a8').activate();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow());
  var source_range = sheet.getRange(row+1,1,1,lastcolumn);
  var target_range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,lastcolumn);
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  sheet.getRange(row,2).activate();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YY");
  sheet.getRange(row,3).activate();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue("");
  sheet.getRange(row,4).activate();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue("");
  sheet.getRange(row,5).activate();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(0);
  sheet.getRange(row,6).activate();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(0);
  sheet.getRange(row,7).activate();
  sheet.getActiveCell().setValue("O");

  sheet.getRange(row,3).activate();
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your code and it is working just fine. I was able to edit the activated cell after running the script. Also, you don't need to activate each cell in order to edit it. You could directly setValue after the getRange.

Here, I modified some parts of your code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
//Add Test Menu everytime the Sheet is opened.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'myFunction', functionName: 'myFunction'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Test Menu', menuItems);
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions");
  var row = 8;
  var lastcolumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(sheet.getRange('A8').getRow());
  var source_range = sheet.getRange(row+1,1,1,lastcolumn);
  var target_range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,lastcolumn);
  source_range.copyTo(target_range);
  sheet.getRange(row,2).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/DD/YY");
  sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue("");
  sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue("");
  sheet.getRange(row,5).setValue(0);
  sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue(0);
  sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue("O");
  sheet.getRange(row,3).activate();  
}
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [getRange(row, col, numRow, numCol)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you said it worked I did an additional test. If I run the script from the editor or a menu selection I created, it works. The button I created seems to be the problem. I drew a square an assigned the script to it. Any thoughts on why this would interfere with the activate?

Comment: For some reason, Sheet is prioritizing the user action(click) rather than the script. I would suggest to create a custom menu instead of button since it will not interfere with the elements of the spreadsheet. See updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks. I have the custom menu and it works fine. I did learn that I could hit ESC after the script and then data entry worked.